# Predictions for Stack Exchange in 2015

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

What are your predictions for the Stack Exchange websites for the year, let's say, 2015?

I will come back to this thread on Jan 1, 2015 (if it is not deleted by then).

'til then, ciao.

Comment: It will most likely be a CW by then.

Comment: Haven't you heard? The world in gonna end before that..

Comment: By 2015, this will likely have been deemed on topic for 'psychics SE' and migrated there.

Comment: It's 2015(and near 2016) now.

Answer (score 25):

Jon has finally overflown the `Int64` rep, and is back to human status.

Comment: So that's your plan to be #1! :)

Comment: Damn, they're onto me...

Comment: I think you mean overflowed?

Comment: No, overflown is correct. There will be an IntJS datatype by then. :)

Comment: Jon is immortal, recently found BigInteger.

Answer (score 20):

At 2015, Front Page of SO is filled up with **closed as duplicate** :-)

Answer (score 12):

I predict two new spinoffs (names will be different):

- **doctoroverflow.com**: Ask questions about your medical problems, get answers from strangers on the internet INSTANTLY.
- **lawyeroverflow.com**: Why pay hundreds of dollars to a lawyer for legal advice?  Lots of people on the internet know every aspect of the law! (Just look at the comments to any news story about intellectual property rights.)  Why not let them answer for free, and the payment will be in the form of their massive rep.

Comment: GOVERNMENT OVERTHROW!

Comment: hahaha, I like your lawyer idea. Everyone is correct on the Internet!

Comment: [Law.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) was created around May 2015; [MedicalSciences.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/medical-sciences) [formerly Health.SE] was created around March 2015.  This prediction was fairly accurate!

Answer (score 9):

I predict TheTXI will become a moderator of SuperUser, and eventually MSO.

Comment: Well the first half has already come true...

Comment: OMG! NO WAI! I AM THE MOST AWESOMEST PREDICTOR MAN IN THE WORLD!

Comment: When did that happen?

Comment: Kyle: About 20 minutes ago :P

Comment: @Kyle: Right after I predicted it!

Comment: hmmm... I think we'd have to check the clocks very carefully ;-p

Comment: lol, nice

Answer (score 7):

I predict all of the sites will be infested by references to ponies.

Comment: Assuming your first suggestion comes true, it's not that much of a stretch.

Comment: @Joel: Oh, did you not get that memo?

Comment: I have to conserve the pony references or they start to become dull.

Comment: That doesn't stop the rest of us from making pony references.

Comment: One of us! One of us!

Answer (score 6):

Upon achieving a critical knowledge mass of 1.5 million questions and answers, SO will become self aware and engulf the "lesser" sites. After determining that Jon Skeet is a threat to its superiority, SOnet will eliminate him by posting a C# question that is impossible to answer yet so devilishly mesmerizing that Jon will starve to death at his computer trying to solve it. With no one standing in its way, SOnet will insert [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469445/last-words-of-a-programmer/469561#469561) into the software of every military organization in the world:

```
if (launchMissiles = true)
{
   FireNukes();
}
```

Comment: Best coding practices could avoid it http://xkcd.com/534/

Answer (score 6):

In 2015 we can fight over who answers this question with some funny comment about already being 2015, get some upvotes, earning a new **Necromancer** badge.

Comment: I think this prediction is the most likely of the whole bunch. You'll look like a genius in five years (can you feel it yet?).

Comment: Hey! I just earned a necromancer badge for this post!

Answer (score 5):

I predict people will never stop crying about 'abusive' edits instead of reporting them to moderators.

Answer (score 5):

I predict Joel fires Jeff and takes over development of SO and SE solely with Fogcreek.

Comment: ouch.........15

Comment: .....in Wasabi.

Comment: That would not be good for me :(

Comment: Is their business arrangement set up so that's even possible?

Comment: Too early. Jeff already left.

Comment: ...That would be the definition of a prediction.

Answer (score 5):

Since we all know the [Aztecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incas) installed a [vacuum metastability device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_bomb) on their rock calendars in [Guatemala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uruguay) set to destroy [the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Pyramids) on [December 21, 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), we all know these predictions [will never be proven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goedel%27s_incompleteness_theorems).

Enjoy your alternate set of physical constants.

#### Edit:

But of course, [one man](http://thestupidestmanonearth.com) can save us all.

Comment: Time will run backwards, gravity will only affect things without mass, and up will be blue.

Comment: "Did everything just taste purple for a second?"

Comment: Psssh, I predict a pothead with magic rocks will dance and save our world. http://www.thestupidestmanonearth.com

Comment: The "one man" link is broken. It's not pointing to Jon Skeet's profile.

Answer (score 4):

I predict SO will still exist, unless it doesn't.

Comment: And if it doesn't, no one will read this. Genius!

Answer (score 3):

I predict the term "stackoverflow" will be redefined in all text books..

Answer (score 3):

Everyone on the internet will have over 10K reputation, and the *delete wars* will be worse than the *close wars* from when you needed only one vote to close.

Comment: Meh, there are already 500 10k+ users and I've only seen two delete wars so far.

Answer (score 2):

I predict the stackoverflow podcast will push the 3 hour mark.

Really didn't think I would be proved wrong so quick.

Comment: would you care to revise this statement?

Answer (score 2):

In 2015, Markdown Editor will support all the html tags

Answer (score 1):

I predict we see at least many more "Make people comment on down votes" suggestions on MSO.

Comment: This one isn't realistic at all. 200 is much too loose a lower bound!

Comment: @welbog: Better?

Answer (score 0):

In 2015 all privileges will be raised by 10 times so that new users can not earn any rep and Jon will be on the frontpage daliy,

Answer (score 0):

`reavers.stackexchange.com` will cannibalize every other SE sites and the final battle with SO will be cancelled by Fox due to budget cuts.

Answer (score -1):

In 2015 , there will be , upvote and downvote for Post editor, single sign on to every channel without request / grant access first